# defining custom UI logic in JSF for <script> tags

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, taglib

I know about creating my own taglibs in JSF eg.  but is there a way to use JSF to parse differently native HTML elements? I am thinking of adding my own parameters for forms, divs, that would be then parsed differently on the server before rendering the final markup.

Comment: What do you mean by *parsed differently* ?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bad idea to me.  Your apps will always be tied to JSF and your custom components.

I'll guarantee that someday a team of developers will curse you when they refactor the whole thing to use HTML 5 and CSS 3. I'd recommend not doing it, but that's just my opinion.

I don't see how this fits in with AJAX, Flex, or Flash.  It has a 90s feel to me.

Comment: Wouldn't that be the case for most of the markup used in JSF applications then? It's all written in tag libs, not pure HTML...

Comment: Yes, it is.  That's another reason why I don't like JSF.

Comment: Actually, the OP's requirement is also not possible in JSF :)